# Is there a way of returning the value of a dictionary where the key is a KeyValuePair or a class without iterating?

Tags: c#, loops, dictionary

I'm not sure I've managed to word the title too well unfortunately, so let me jump straight into an example:
Say I have the following Dictionary:

```
Dictionary<KeyValuePair<int, string>, float> dict;
```

Now I create a method which takes an int and a string and returns a float.

```
float GetFloatFromDict(int _int, string _string)
{
    return buttonMappings[new KeyValuePair<int, Gesture>(_controllerNumber, _gesture)];
}
```

If we call this method passing in `1` and `one` and we know a Dictionary entry exists with the key being a KeyValuePair with these values it doesn't work because we're creating a new object and it's not going to be the same as any existing object in the dictionary.

Is it possible to do this but have it search for the key with the values without manually iterating through?

Is there a better way to do this than the following? Also is there a nice way to handle to suitable entry being found?

```
float GetFloatFromDict(int _int, string _string)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<int, string> _key in dict.Keys)
    {
        if(_key.Key == _int && _key.Value == _String)
        {
            return dict[_key];
        }
    }
    //If nothing found, return some float
}
```

Comment: Why in the heck would you use a KeyValuePair as a key for a Dictionary??

Comment: Use a `Tuple<int, string>`, I think it has the equality comparisons you are looking for.

Comment: Have you tried using a Tuple<int, string> ?

Comment: "If we call this method passing in `1` and `one` and we know a Dictionary entry exists with the key being a `KeyValuePair` with these values it doesn't work because we're creating a new object and it's not going to be the same as any existing object in the dictionary." Except this shouldn't be true, because `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` has the expected comparison semantics. `new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "one").Equals(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "one"))`. Have you actually tried it?

Comment: Using Unity and unfortunately therefore a version of mono which doesn't support Tuples. KeyValuePair is just an example to make the question quickly understandable as opposed to just a class with two values.

Comment: @JeroenMostert Dictionary works with `GetHashCode` and then `Equals` method. hashcode is the reason that you can access items directly.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary: yes, and `KeyValuePair` overrides both (implicitly, from `ValueType`, since it's a `struct`). Using it as a dictionary key works just fine.

Comment: Even without `Tuple<...>` you can create your own more sensible key type than using `KeyValuePair`.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - You're right, it actually does work. I had tried with a custom class but with a `KeyValuePair` it works fine, my bad!


@JonSkeet - What is so bad about using a `KeyValuePair` over a custom equivalent implementation? I assume it's partly that `Key` and `Value` aren't especially useful names.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of `Dictionary`:

> Dictionary requires an equality implementation to
>   determine whether keys are equal. You can specify an implementation of
>   the IEqualityComparer generic interface by using a constructor that
>   accepts a comparer parameter; if you do not specify an implementation,
>   the default generic equality comparer EqualityComparer.Default is
>   used. If type TKey implements the System.IEquatable generic
>   interface, the default equality comparer uses that implementation.

So you should either create a custom IEqualityComparer and pass it to the Dictionary or use a subclass of KeyValuePair that implements IEquatable.

Comment: That's assuming that `KeyValuePair` doesn't handle equality properly. I believe it should do, inheriting the behaviour from `ValueType`. It's possible that Unity is broken on that front though...

Comment: You can't subclass `KeyValuePair` since it's a `struct`. Implementing your own type that implements `IEquatable` would make more sense.